# django fill form field automatically from context data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form attached to a DetailedView and its working fine when saved. I would like the form field(position) to be prepopulated with the value coming from the slug of the detailed view(e.g jobs/human-resource-manager). The Model of the form field has a Foreignkey to the JobPost model. Need help. Part of my view looks like this

```
class JobsDetailView(DetailView):
model = JobPost
template_name = 'job_post-detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(JobsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['position'] = JobPost.objects.order_by('position')
    context['job_app_form'] = JobsForm()
    return context
```

foms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from job_post.models import JobsApplied


class JobsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = JobsApplied
      fields = '__all__'

  def form_valid(self, form):
     form.instance.customuser = self.request.user
     return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you do not want your users to be able to interact with or change these prefilled values.

I'm making a comments/review model and I want it to automatically link reviews to the people they are about

**models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

I hide the person field in the ReviewsForm to prevent user input by either omitting it from the 'fields' or adding it to an 'exclude'.

**forms.py**

```
class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Review
    fields = ('rating', 'summary', 'review_text')
```

Then, when processing the form in the view, I use commit=False so I can manipulate field values before saving to the database.
Include prefilled values, save and then redirect the user wherever is ideal

**views.py**

```
def person(request, area_slug, category_slug, person_id):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        pending_review = form.save(commit=False)
        pending_review.person = Person.objects.get(pk = person_id)
        pending_review.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

django fill form field automatically from context data for django form and django formsets

For formsets in forms.py

```
StoreRequestAccessoryUpdateFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(StoreRequestAccessory, form=StoreRequestAccessoryUpdateForm, exclude=["storeRequestId"], can_delete=True)
```

In get_context_data you can add it as you like for django

```
class StoreRequestUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = "Inventory/Stock/StoreRequest/StoreRequestUpdateView.html"
    model = StoreRequest
    fields = ["fromStoreId", "toStoreId", "reference", "status", "remark"]
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StoreRequestUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        print(self.object.pk)
    context.update({
                # "StoreRequestForm": context.get("form"),
                "StoreRequestForm": StoreRequestUpdateForm(instance=StoreRequest.objects.get(id=self.object.pk)),
                "StoreRequestAccessoryForm": StoreRequestAccessoryUpdateFormSet(
                    queryset=StoreRequestAccessory.objects.filter(storeRequestId=self.object.pk), 
                    prefix="storereq_accessory_form"),
    })

    return context
```